# Normal motherboard and CPU temperature

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard, temperature

What is the normal temperature of motherboard and CPU?

Details:

- Model: Toshiba SATELLITE T130
- Mainboard: Toshiba SATELLITE T130
- Total Memory: 3.84 GB DDR3 SO-DIMM
- Processor: Genuine Intel(R) CPU U4100 @ 1.30 GHz (2C 1.3 GHz, 2 MB L2)

The SpeedFan application shows the following results:

- Core 1 and Core 2: ~45 °C
- Hard disk drive: ~28 °C
- Motherboard temp 52-56 °C

PS: Are there better temperature diagnostic tools?

Comment: CPU temp very reasonable. CPUs go up to 60-70 C although not desirable. HDD temp is about average at 28 C. Motherboard temp seems very high at 52-56 C. Are you sure SpeedFan is reading the correct temp for motherboard?

Comment: Thanks for reply : here is also results from other tool PC Wizard :  Hardware Monitoring : ACPI 
THRM : 52 °C    
 : 
Processor Intel Pentium : Sensor DTS  
Core 1 : 42 °C  
Core 2 : 42 °C 
Hard Disk Monitoring : S.M.A.R.T
Hard Disk TOSHIBA MK3263GSX : 28 °C

Comment: @Peter Fowler :In continue to previous comment : do you think that here are fan problem ?

Comment: I assume this is a laptop and is possibly 3-4 years old. Laptops often get blocked fans. Is there plenty of air coming from the fan outlet?

Comment: Yes, you're right - it is laptop ~3.5 year old . Some air is coming from the outlet. I think it should be checked in lab. Thanks for replies

Comment: Chaps, please put answers into answers rather than comments.

Answer (score 1):

These temperatures seem OK to me.

My Lenovo ThinkPad i5 laptop is fairly new (last year) and is currently showing core temps of around 43-50 with a max of 58

HDD temp is around 28 and stable.

As stated by Peter, the motherboard temp seems a little highbut not excessively, mine isn't reported by the [Open Hardware Monitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/downloads/) tool I'm using. Some laptops have a special fan mode that will do a blast of air to clear out any crud. Look under the manufactures power settings tool.

The best test for temp problems is to leave the laptop with nothing running for a while - maybe 1/2 hour - then measure the temps. If they are still high, check that there isn't either a service or an application that hasn't closed properly by looking at the task manager for things reporting >1% CPU.

If there aren't any, try putting a vacuum to the fan outlets for a minute or so to see if you can clear out any fluff.

Comment: According to SpeedFan on 1/2 hour idle ACPI THRM was ~47C while CPU was ~38 . Are this numbers look OK ? Thanks

Comment: CPU is fine, maybe the motherboard is running a little hot but it isn't too excessive. Try the trick with the vacuum cleaner if you like, it doesn't hurt. But overall, I don't think you've anything to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

For a laptop, you have an average temperature, which means you're on the safe side for a normal usage. However, the temperature will go up if there is more data processing, also there is a small heat lack.

The average temperature in a normal usage should be between 21-40 C to all of your hardware, that includes motherboard. Some hardware can handle more than that, but it doesn't mean it's okay if it hits more than 48 then it's overheating.

A CPU & GPU are exception on mid to heavy usage because there are more data to process, thus, the temperature of CPU & GPU will increase, that increase will make it around %20 to %40 of the normal usage temperature in regular bases, if is it increasing more than that, then there is a cooling issue such as bad airflow, broken fans, or incompatible cooling system (e.g cooling system is not designed for heavy usage) and so on.

A normal usage is what most people do on computers such as browsing, documenting or doing light tasks. While mid-usage and heavy usage are considered to those who use more data processing such as video montage, gaming, 3D designing, Graphics design, overclocked systems ..etc.

If you know in which category are you, then you will know if your hardware temperature is normal or overheated.

I use Speccy, it gives me the temperature of each hardware that I have, which is easier for me to see which part is overheating.

Also, your motherboard is overheated a bit more than usual. Which means that your computer doesn't have enough airflow to go in and out, and from the CPU temperature, I think you have a problem with your fan or the CPU thermal paste is getting solid. If the CPU heated up, then the motherboard temperature will be increased as well.

**To verify wither the issue from your CPU or fan Do the following:**

Check the fan is working probably by putting your hand next to the fan gaps, and see if there is a strong or weak air. if is it weak then the fan needs to be replaced, if is it strong then shut down your computer and leave it for 5 minutes to cool it down, then turn it back on, do not open anything, just check the CPU temperature and see if is it between 21-40 (keep monitoring it for a minute or so), then you don't have a problem with your thermal compound. if is it  more than 40, then it's a thermal compound issue. If you need more time to fix this issue, you can use cooling pad as a temporary solution, until you fix it.